# Display Wordpress Content on another website

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, rss

I have a wordpress site, it's been set up with some custom post types.

I'd like to display one of these post types on another website. Another Wordpress website that is hosted by a different company and uses it's own database.

Specially, I'd like to display the last 8 items of my post type on a page on their website.

I would also like to style the feed, I'm assuming these styles could be put in the head of the page where the feed is being displayed, or imported from a separate file.

What is the best way of displaying Wordpress content on an external site?

I've been wondering about these options
 - Use my RSS feed and style the resulting HTML (don't know where to start here).
 - In the PHP connect to my database and pull in the posts as if it was on my website.

I feel really stuck as to where to start. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read the RSS Feed. Connect to a remote database is more costly. 
This code read the RSS feed and print the result:

```
function getFeed($feed_url) {

    $content = file_get_contents($feed_url);
    $x = new SimpleXmlElement($content);

    echo "<ul>";

    foreach($x->channel->item as $entry) {
        echo "<li><a href='$entry->link' title='$entry->title'>" . $entry->title . "</a></li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}

getFeed("http://your-wordpress-site/feed/");
```

Add a CSS class to the LI element and it's done.

Comment: Thanks for your clear answer.  I was leaning towards the RSS feed route because I'd hate to lessen security in anyway by connecting databases across sites. Regarding your code, I've tried running the function on a test wordpress install and tempted to pull in a feed. I placed it directly into a page template and changed the feed url but I get nothing. Any ideas?

Comment: Please, run a phpinfo(); and make sure you have enabled SimpleXML extension and allow_url_fopen = On.

Comment: I'm working on this via a local copy on my computer. Using MAMP. I've checked on the site I'm wanting the RSS feed from and my local version, they both have the SimpleXML extension enabled and allow_url_fopen is set to On.

Comment: Ok, I just sat down with this again. Turns out I was being a total idiot! I forgot to update the page when I changed the template! doh! It's showing the feed list fine. I think I could take it from here, add the extra elements and hopefully style it with some css. Thank you.